# Executing Springboot application as jar gives "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I use different ways to get jar by idea.But when I input `java -jar ****.jar`.It is tell me `no main manifest attribute, in quark-common.jar`

It's url of my project:`https://github.com/ZYao123/JavaQuarkBBS`.The project has 5 modules.They can work on my idea,but when I want to package a jar for linux. The problems arise.
The module is depend on `quark-parent`.`quark-parent` just has a `pom.xml` for public package.
I have added this on `pom.xml` of `quark-common`,but they cann't work.
I know it happend because it's cann't find main method,but how am I supposed to fix it?

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>quark-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.quark</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../quark-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.quark</groupId>
<artifactId>quark-common</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>quark-common</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar guava-19.0.jar hibernate-jpa-
 2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar spring-expression-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar tools.ja
 r dom4j-1.6.1.jar spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar spri
 ng-boot-starter-cache-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar spring-aspects-4.3.10.RELEASE
 .jar druid-1.0.29.jar spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar spring-context-4.
 3.10.RELEASE.jar javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar spring-
 boot-starter-aop-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar nekohtml-1.9.22.jar spring-boot-st
 arter-jdbc-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar antlr
 -2.7.7.jar log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar 
 jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar jconsole.jar javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar sp
 ring-boot-starter-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar log
 back-classic-1.1.11.jar spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar fastjs
 on-1.2.16.jar spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEA
 SE.jar spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar spring-co
 ntext-support-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar snakeyaml-1.17.jar hibernate-commons
 -annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar xml-apis-1.4.01.jar jboss-logging-3.3.1.
 Final.jar logback-core-1.1.11.jar aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar ehcache-2.
 10.4.jar jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.
 jar jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE
 .jar tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.6.RELEASE
 .jar hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar 
 spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar tomcat-juli-8.5.16.jar
Main-Class: com.quark.common.CommonApplication
```

Comment: is there a public static void main(String[] args)  method in the quark-common project and is this class public ?

Comment: Remove packing tag of Jar and look how it works

Comment: can you show your SpringBootApplication class ??

Answer (score 1):

So I've build you project locally and manifest in `quark-common.jar` is something like that:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
    Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.2
    Built-By: ...
    Build-Jdk: 10.0.2
```

It has no main class and other properties are also lacking.
The reason is that you dont have needed configuration for `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. It should be something like:

```
  . . .
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>repackage</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
. . .
```

Result `MANIFEST.MF` would be something like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.2
Built-By: ...
Build-Jdk: 10.0.2
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.quark.common.CommonApplication
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.5.6.RELEASE
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib
```

And then you run your app with `java -jar quark-common-exec.jar` (it creates an additional executable artifact with `exec` extension).

Hope this would help you.

**Update**

Answering you question:

I suppose this happen because you are using `spring-boot-dependencies` bom (it provides). And in your other project u have used `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent to your module. Like that:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

So it has all required plugin configs. And `spring-boot-dependencies` bom doesnt, it just provides versions of dependencies and plugins.

Comment: The `MANIFEST.MF` is create by idea. it's ok. I edit my pom.xml like yours,and It worked,Thank you bery much.But I want to know why my another project is ok without `executions` node. The version of springboot is `2.0.4.RELEASE`.Because of version?I don't know.It's like magic

Comment: @zhang_ Updated original answer.

Comment: very nice, yes I use`spring-boot-starter-parent`.Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue and the problem with my pom was, spring-boot-maven-plugin was inside pluginManagement node

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I changed pom configuration as given below and it started working and generated correct MANIFEST.MF

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```